# How many known plaintexts are required to break a system with this property?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Suppose we have an $n$ bit block cipher $E$ with a key $k$ that has the following property
$$E(k; m_1⊕m_2) = E(k;m_1) ⊕E(k; m_2).$$
How
many minimum number of chosen plaintexts are required to decipher
(with probability 1) a given ciphertext (not from the list of ciphetexts
corresponding to the chosen plaintexts) without knowing $k$
and what would be those plaintexts be.

I figured replacing $m_2$ with a n-bit string of all 1's can give us $$E(m')=E(m)'$$ where $m'$ is one's complement of the bit string.

I cannot think of anything further than this. Not knowing the encryption algorithm seems to be a hurdle, although my teacher said it should not be.

Comment: And, is this homework? We call this homomorphic encryption.  An example is [Golderwasser-Micali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwasser-Micali_cryptosystem)

Comment: @kelalaka: "although my teacher said it should not be" - I assume that it is either homework or a classroom exercise...

Comment: Hint: Find two messages that their encryptions' x-or is the target ciphertext!